# HTML5 canvas issue with Internet explorer

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I am creating a web site where end users can upload a photo and have it superimpose under a calendar as a gift

All works perfectly in Chrome or FF, however in IE I have an issue with scaling the image, it only scales in the x axis meaning it squishes the image rather than makes the whole image bigger or smaller.

When you click on the plus or minus sign to scale the image, I am changing the inline width style for the canvas element.

I have tested it on IE 9 and 10, any ideas whatis going on?

Here is the link - http://www.submitphoto.com.au/new/diary.php

Comment: Your app works appropriately in IE11. But I can reproduce your problem in IE10 emulation mode. Your link to the complete code is appreciated, but please present a small snippet of code where you are having problems (digging through your complete codebase is lengthy).

Comment: This is the HTML - 

<canvas id="imgBig" class="uploadedImage" width="1024" height="768" style="width: 582px;"></canvas>

Clicking the minus button changes the width, which it does but the height of the object does not change.

After some Googling it seems to be an issue with CSS style conflicting with the inline styles, but i still can't work it out

Comment: sorted it out - i added the height to the javascript code that was changing the width, it now works ok in IE